# Link Access Database to Google Map API

Tags: javascript, html, database

I have a database with about 20 locations based in Europe.

I want to link this database (Access 2007) to a Google map (which can be embedded into a webpage, or just linked to) which will allow me to see which locations store a specific product.

i.e I store product 1 in Germany and Italy. I want to choose product 1, and see both locations. 
I store product 2 in Germany, UK and Netherlands. If I choose product 2, I want all three locations to appear. The 20 sites are static and will not change.

I want to also be able to pull a field "Inventory" from the database, and show in the text box of the location marker, if this is possible.

Has anyone got any ideas?

Thanks,
Cathal